# how to plot list of tuples, generated by groupby

Tags: python-3.x

I want to plot each list of tuples generated by groupby command.

```
import more_itertools as mit
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,0,1,2,3], 'b':[2,10,24,56,90,1,3]})
for group in mit.consecutive_groups(zip(df['a'],df['b']),ordering=lambda t:t[0]):
     print(list(group))
```

output:
    `[(0, 2), (1, 10),(2,24)] 
       [(0,56),(1,90),(2,1),(3,3)]`

I want to plot first index of group `[(0, 2), (1, 10),(2,24)]` taking first element as x and second element of tuple as y ( x=0,y=2). The same applies to following list of tuples. I am still trying, but have not figured yet.

Comment: Use groupby from pandas? Something with cumsum of (diff of a != 1)... Not a pandas guy, but pretty sure you can do something like that.

Comment: using the idea of @MadPhysicist you could use `df.assign(grp = df.a.diff().ne(1).cumsum())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
df.assign(grp = df.a.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).groupby('grp').plot('a','b')
```

Comment: The first or last element of grp will be nan, no? You probably need to fill it with 1...

Comment: @MadPhysicist with pandas, since we are comparing `ne(1)` the `nan` will be treated as not being equal to 1, thus giving a `true`. this is weird to me too  since I have `R` background, whereby we cant have a `NAN` comparison

Comment: Wouldn't you want something like `df.a.diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum()`? It won't matter if it's the first element since that just adds one to the cumsum, but you don't want your last element isolated for no reason if that's where the nan ends up. Not a pandas guy, and on mobile, so can't test.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean by `ffill()`?? you cannot forward fill since the `nan` is the first element and not the last.

Comment: @MadPhysicist and Onyambu, would you help me grouping the consecutive integers having the same number of rows or counts. for example I want to group  {0,1,2},{0,1,2} as one group and {0,1,2,3} as another group

Comment: @JoVin. I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that that's a separate question. You should ask it as such, since I don't really understand what you want from a single comment without an example. Feel free to ping us in the comments.